# Is there a way to make hyperlinks in code/comments not clickable?

Tags: r, rstudio, comments

When I add a URL or file path to my comments, it defaults to being clickable.

For example:

```
# http://stackoverflow.com
```

Is there a way to turn this off? I'm not finding anything in Tools >> Global Options.

Comment: I don't see anything in the [RStudio Themes](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rstudio-theme-creation.html) discussion, perhaps you can add a bug report? (For me, though, while it underlines as a link, it doesn't become clickable for me until I `Shift-Click`. Is that what you're trying to avoid? I'm on win-10, RStudio-1.2.5042.)

Comment: @r2evans yes, I'm frequently trying to copy paste the link, and shift + click gets in the way. Also if I'm updating the content of a local link, I'd rather not have it open.

Comment: Good suggestion, @r2evans. I've opened a feature request here: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6689